# how can pylint msg "too many local variables" be disabled

Tags: python, python-3.x, pylint

I am working on eclipse editor and using eclipse plugin `pydev`. I have also installed `pylint` plugin. But `pylint` is throwing me warning messages in some functions like "`too many local arguments`". I don't want to change my code. Is there any way to disable those warnings, especially this one. I do have a `~/.pylintrc` file. What should I add to that file to disable these warning messages.

Comment: [First google result](https://stackoverflow.com/a/816549/1509809)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can modify the `max-locals` for local variable and `max-args` for method arguments in .pylintrc file

```
[DESIGN]

# Maximum number of locals for function / method body
max-locals=25

# Maximum number of arguments for function / method
max-args=10
```

from : [source](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/blob/master/pylintrc)

Answer (score 14):

If you need to skip pylint validation for some specific function then add the line (comment)

```
# pylint: disable-msg=too-many-locals
```

inside that function. You may add this line right after the function declaration.